# Need simple way to modify the toString() used by JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I currently have a JTable of Class Objects, but would like to display the simple name (example: xyz) instead of the full name (example: class abc.def.ghi.jkl.mno.xyz) while still keeping the Objects in the JTable as Class.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: `toString` is a poor choice for creating displayable output.  In Swing, you are better of using the appropriate cell renderers, which allows you to change the way a object is display across multiple different components (`JList`, `JTable`, `JTree`, `JComboBox` for example)...

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a custom renderer for that column of the table.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) for more information. The example in the tutorial shows how to format a date, so you would modify the code to format your string.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create a subclass of that and redefine `toString()` method to return the class simple name?

Answer (score 0):

Use Class.getSimpleName() instead of toString